# MPI Error while running code on multiple nodes of cluster

Tags: c, centos, mpi, cluster-computing, hpc

I am using a 4 node cluster with 12 cores on each node and a master node. I have compiled the code [gerris](http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on master node and copied the libraries on all nodes. When I run a parallel job on one node it works fine but when I run a job on multiple nodes then it shows up the error:

```
PE 9 (compute-0-1.local): error when cleaning up /tmp/2547.1.all.q/gfsB80OGX
```

---

mpirun noticed that process rank 4 with PID 25128 on node compute-0-1.local exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

Earlier the code was compiled using pre-build packages as provided on the website and it used to work perfectly fine even on multiple nodes but now I have made some changes in the code and using the developer version and compiled it from the scratch.
Can anyone suggest something on how to debug this error. I am not able to find anything on google regarding this error. 
Update 1: June 1
This is the error I got when I tried GDB.

```
warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libm.so.6" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libdl.so.2" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libnsl.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libutil.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libpthread.so.0" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/libc.so.6" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/librt.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib64/librdmacm.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib64/libibverbs.so.1" is not at the expected address

warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsC0YVGX/module.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsLB2CGX/module.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsSNFHGX/module.so: No such file or directory.
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsW7MLGX/module.so: No such file or directory.
Reading symbols from /opt/gerris/lib/libgfs3D-1.3.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/gerris/lib/libgfs3D-1.3.so.2
Reading symbols from /opt/gerris/lib/libgts-0.7.so.5...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/gerris/lib/libgts-0.7.so.5
Reading symbols from /lib64/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libmpi.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libmpi.so.0
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libopen-rte.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libopen-rte.so.0
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libopen-pal.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libopen-pal.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libutil.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libutil.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libimf.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libimf.so
Reading symbols from /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libsvml.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libsvml.so
Reading symbols from /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/intel/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5
Reading symbols from /lib64/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_linux.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_linux.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_carto_auto_detect.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_env.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_env.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_binomial.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_routed_binomial.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so
Reading symbols from /lib64/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_basic.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_basic.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_bucket.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_allocator_bucket.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_rcache_vma.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_rcache_vma.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_fake.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_fake.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_rdma.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_rdma.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_sm.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_sm.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libmca_common_sm.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/libmca_common_sm.so.1
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/librdmacm.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/librdmacm.so.1.0.0.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/librdmacm.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libibverbs.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libibverbs.so.1.0.0.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libibverbs.so.1
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_self.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_self.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_sm.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_tcp.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_tcp.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_basic.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_basic.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_hierarch.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_hierarch.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_inter.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_inter.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_self.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sm.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sm.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_sync.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_tuned.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_pt2pt.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_pt2pt.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_rdma.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_osc_rdma.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libmlx4-rdmav2.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libmlx4-rdmav2.so.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libmlx4-rdmav2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libmthca-rdmav2.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libmthca-rdmav2.so.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libmthca-rdmav2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libipathverbs-rdmav2.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libipathverbs-rdmav2.so.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libipathverbs-rdmav2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libnes-rdmav2.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libnes-rdmav2.so.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libnes-rdmav2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libcxgb3-rdmav2.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libcxgb3-rdmav2.so.debug...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libcxgb3-rdmav2.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_pubsub_orte.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_pubsub_orte.so
Reading symbols from /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_dpm_orte.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /opt/mpi/openmpi/1.4.3/intel/lib/openmpi/mca_dpm_orte.so
Symbol file not found for /tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsC0YVGX/module.so
Symbol file not found for /tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsLB2CGX/module.so
Symbol file not found for /tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsSNFHGX/module.so
Symbol file not found for /tmp/2563.1.all.q/gfsW7MLGX/module.so
Core was generated by `/opt/gerris/bin/gerris3D ./pswirl.gfs'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002b320e9d00f0 in ?? ()
```

Comment: It sounds like your problem might be related to having different versions of your library being used on different nodes. Are you sure that you're using the correct code? Can you link the library statically into the executable so you don't have to put the libraries on the nodes?

Comment: Linking the libraries statically opens new can of worms in itself which I don't want to touch right now. So that is not an option.
Is there any other way I can figure out the specific problem like using valgrind or anything. I am not very experienced with coding.

Comment: Without knowing a lot of things like, which MPI implementation you're using, what system you're on, what you code is, etc., it's hard to give a definitive answer here. Unfortunately, debugging parallel code is hard and requires learning some debugging tools like valgrind, gdb, totalview, etc.

Comment: Hey Wesley, thank you for your reply. Please have a look at the output generated by GDB. I would be happy to share any more info you want. I really need to debug this error.